# XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been looking for a node module that supports XML to HTML/XSL version 2.0 transformations via XSLT. I'm confined to developing in a windows environment, and have researched many alternatives including Saxon/C (saxon-node), node_xslt, gulp-xslt, and some others.

I haven't found a solution that satisfies our needs. Most solutions seem to require a linux or mac osx environment for development.

Any ideas? I greatly appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2020 Update

*[Saxon-JS 2](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) now [supports XSLT 3.0 in Node.js and in the browser](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml)!*

---

**Former answer**: Your best bet for XSLT in Node.js would be [Saxon-JS](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml), which is a XSLT 3.0 runtime in pure JavaScript<sup>1</sup>.  Note that you'll need [Saxon-EE](http://www.saxonica.com/shop/shop.html#!/Individual-Licenses/c/905991/offset=0&sort=normal), a commercial product, to compile your XSLT, but once that's done, you can [freely deploy the result and the runtime](http://www.saxonica.com/license/paid-license.html).  As a bonus, Saxon-JS implements not only XSLT 2.0 but XSLT 3.0 as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>**Caveat**: Saxon-JS will clearly be your best bet once Saxonica adds support for parsing and serialization to the JavaScript runtime.  Before then, [these limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309668/windows-compatible-node-js-xslt-package-the-supports-xsl-2-0-and-xml-to-html/45310013#comment77584783_45310013) will severely restrict the  suitability of Saxon-JS to many projects, including possibly yours.

Comment: Brilliant! Was just talking to the department director about Saxon, I'm glad that's a good alternative. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: We've had reports of people using Saxon-JS under Node.js but it's not actually something that Saxonica yet supports, though we would like to do so. In terms of features, we're aware that Saxon-JS is optimized for the browser environment (for example, it doesn't contain a serializer and relies on the browser for XML parsing). But feel free to see how far you get with it, and give us feedback.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I'd forgotten about those limitations; thank you for being forthright in mentioning.  Answer updated.  *My* feedback would be to wish to see you continue the great work of building a world-class XSLT implementation in JavaScript by providing a parser and serializer without browser dependency.  Even for in-browser applications, I would prefer to use your parser and serializer over that of the browser.  (Yes, even at the cost of *any* increase in download size of the runtime library.)