# Resolving documents and collections from memory

Tags: node.js, xslt

I've got an application that needs to support XSLT 2/3 with a very specific requirement regarding how documents are resolved.

It must support multiple inputs (ie, docs pulled into the transform via fn:doc and fn:collection) and outputs (with xsl:result-document) where these documents will be located in application memory rather than on disk, requiring custom resolvers/finders/etc to pass the documents into/out of the transformation.

I'm struggling to find a Node.js XSLT package that supports this.

In the Saxon world, the Java and C# API allow this (can specify input and output resolvers and a collection finder), but I can't see a way of doing this with the C API that saxon-node uses, for example (neither in the js or C API), nor via libxslt.

Does anyone know if this is possible with the Node.js packages currently available?

Comment: Your question amounts to asking for a XSLT 2.0 library for Node.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT 2.0 for Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309668/windows-compatible-node-js-xslt-package-the-supports-xsl-2-0-and-xml-to-html)

Comment: No - just XLST 2 is more generic and already provided by some packages.  I'm after specific features here - apologies if I didn't make that more obvious but the title is about resolving documents from memory.

Comment: Why the downvote?  For the 'ducplicate question' that isn't a duplicate?

Comment: I didn't downvote you (+1 to counter), but consider that despite your denial, your edited question and your comment follow-ups still do not ask for anything other than XSLT 2.0 running under Node.js.   Furthermore, you state that XSLT 2.0 is "already provided by some packages," which I do not believe to be true in native JS.  (Name one if you know of one.  I would be very happy to learn of one.)