# Using regex in XPath?

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath

I am using the following XPath instruction in a JS function that highlights certain keywords on web pages:

```
var xpath = "//text()[contains(., \"" + keyword + "\")]";
```

Any idea on how I could rewrite it in order to support regex? I tried in various ways, but nothing seemed to work!

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/how-to-use-regex-in-xpath-contains-function

Comment: show the community, what you already tried, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite

```
var xpath = "//text()[contains(., \"" + keyword + "\")]";
```

using regex as

```
var xpath = "//text()[matches(., \"" + keyword + "\")]";
```

and then `keyword` could be a regex rather than only a string.

However, regex functions such as `matches()` require XPath 2.0+.  Native XPath libraries in browsers only support XPath 1.0.

### See also

- [XPath 3 in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48043476/290085)
- [Does Chrome use XPath 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25455351/290085)
- [XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 for Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45309668/290085)

Comment: I already tried using 'matches' instead of 'contains', but it does not work! However, your answer was very useful to me, because it's now clear why this is not working... XPath libraries in browsers only support XPath 1.0! Thank you for your answer, and the links you provided. Very helpful!

Comment: Kenneth, do you think xpath.js (https://github.com/ilinsky/xpath.js) would be helpful in my case? If so, how should the XPath query look like, based on the code I already provided above? There is also jquery-xpath.js (https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath). I'd like to mention that I run my highlighting script using Tampermonkey.

Comment: Sorry, there are too many undefined requirements for me to advise you based on your comment, and this is not the right forum for design advice.  I won't extend this dialog further but will leave you with this thought:  If you're only searching text as your current XPath suggests, and regex is important to you, consider abandoning XPath and using the browser's built-in support for regex directly.  Good luck.

Comment: Sure, I completely understand. Thank you very much!